# Firefox requires some user media for WebRTC call

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I have following code to create a WebRTC connection. I want just one way stream from server to caller.

```
const RTCCon = new RTCPeerConnection({});

WS = new WebSocket(`ws://${location.host}`);
WS.onmessage = e => {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

        RTCCon.setRemoteDescription(data)
                // .then(() =>
                //         window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                //                 audio: true,
                //                 video: false
                //         })
                // )
                .then(() => RTCCon.createAnswer())
                .then(answer => RTCCon.setLocalDescription(answer))
                .then(() => {
                        WS.send(
                                JSON.stringify({
                                        type: "answer",
                                        sdp: RTCCon.localDescription.sdp
                                })
                        );
                        const video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
                        video.muted = true;
                        video.autoplay = true;
                        video.srcObject = new MediaStream(RTCCon.getReceivers().map(receiver => receiver.track));
                });
};
```

This code works with chrome, but does not work with firefox. When I uncommnet the commented part, with the `window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` and allow to use the microphone in browser, the onnection is made and everything works.

It seems there is some issue with ICE candidates. I have multiple network interfaces and one is for internet connection, other is WiFi hotspot, where server is connected. When the connection is not made (without the microphone) ICE candidates are only created with interfaces of the internet connection. When I ask and allow the microphone, ICE candidates with the WiFi hotspot and therefore correct IP is created and used.

It seems that the usermedia and ice connectivity is totally unrelated, but only uncommenting the code makes it work.

I'm not doing any ICE connectivity manipulations on server and the provided code is only js code on client.

Comment: check the ice connection grid in about:webrtc which is helpful in debugging issues

Comment: Yeah, by checking that I found out stuff that I've described in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that when you don't give access to camera or microphone Chrome and Firefox will only give out ICE candidates for the one of your network interfaces. If you have given access to cam/mic they will give out ICE candidates for all interfaces.

Now when they only give out the address for a single interface they need to choose which interface to give out. And right now Firefox will give out the IP address of the interface which routes to 8.8.8.8, so basically your default Internet uplink. Firefox developers are looking into changing that behavior to give out the IP address of the interface from which the page got loaded, which should fix you use case.

I'm not sure why it works in Chrome. Either because Chrome remembers that you previously have given permission to share your cam/mic. Or maybe Chrome already has implemented the same logic which Firefox is about to change to. You should be able to verify that by looking at the ICE candidates Chrome hands out.

Comment: Thanks. But how is microphone associated to ICE? Well chrome, sends the 2 ICEs for the internet connection and one ICE for the wifi.

Comment: It is not really associated. It's just that the ICE networking pieces needed a way to find out how much the user trusts a given page. If you share cam/mic it is assumed the user does that only for pages he/she trusts and therefore it is ok to share more IP addresses. But if the user hasn't given access to cam/mic the page appears less trustworthy and therefore by default less IP addresses should be given out to the page.

Comment: Could / would HTTPS help?

Comment: No there is simply no code in Firefox right now which can tell the ICE stack where the page got loaded from. So HTTP vs HTTPS does not matter for this issue.